# HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently error when debugging AWS Lambda Function locally with IntelliJ AWS Toolkit plugin

Tags: amazon-s3, intellij-idea, aws-lambda

I am receiving the below errors when trying to debug my AWS Lambda function.

`20:38:01.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently[\r][\n]"`

`20:38:01.244 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "x-amz-bucket-region: us-east-1[\r][\n]"`

Part of my confusion is that I am working with buckets normally from ap-south-1 while physically located in us-east-1, and I'm not really sure why us-east-1 is popping up in the records.

My code is a basic function that upon receiving a trigger from an S3 Put, logs some things:

`log.info("Lambda function is invoked: Processing the uploads........." + s3Event.toJson());`

`log.info("File - "+ FileName+" uploaded into "+BucketName+" bucket at "+ s3Event.getRecords().get(0).getEventTime());`

`try (InputStream is = s3client.getObject(BucketName, FileName).getObjectContent()) { log.info("File Contents : "+StreamUtils.copyToString(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));}`

In full,

```
private final String accessKeyId = System.getenv("accessKeyId");
private final String secretAccessKey = System.getenv("secretAccessKey");
private final String region = System.getenv("region");
private final BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
        .standard()
        .withRegion("ap-south-1")
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAWSCredentials))
        .build();
static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(S3EventHandler.class);

@Override
public String handleRequest(S3Event s3Event, Context context) {

    log.info("Lambda function is invoked: Processing the uploads........." + s3Event.toJson());

    String BucketName = s3Event.getRecords().get(0).getS3().getBucket().getName();
    String FileName = s3Event.getRecords().get(0).getS3().getObject().getKey();

    log.info("File - "+ FileName+" uploaded into "+
            BucketName+" bucket at "+ s3Event.getRecords().get(0).getEventTime());
    try (InputStream is = s3client.getObject(BucketName, FileName).getObjectContent()) {
        log.info("File Contents : "+StreamUtils.copyToString(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Error reading contents of the file";
    }
    return null;
}
```

[image]
Using the debug function of the Toolkit plugin, I try and simulate an S3 Put. This sends an S3Event to the S3 Function, and it logs everything:

`lambdas3.S3EventHandler - Lambda function is invoked: Processing the uploads......... (etc)`

`lambdas3.S3EventHandler - File - HappyFace.jpg uploaded into source-bucket bucket at 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`

Until it runs into the code that tries to get the file from the bucket. I'd expect it to return the content of the file, or return an error because the lambda function only received the event and the object wasn't created anywhere,

but instead, it notifies me that something's been "301 Moved Permanently" and something about "x-amz-bucket-region: us-east-1" when everything should've been in `ap-south-1`

So now I'm confused about why my region is being changed, and why I'm getting this error instead of one of the two outcomes I expected.

Answer (score 0):

That looks to be an old version of the client. I'm guessing the 301 is adding Https

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/GetObjectData.java

When running code on Aws try and avoid keys and secrets. You can assign a role to the lambda in this case and use https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.html

To pick up the credentials.